# Setting up subdomains

Tags: networking, subdomain

Rookie question here. Please correct any shortcomings in my knowledge so far.

If I have the domain ex1.example.com and wanted to have it point to one server and then had another server on the same external IP address be referred to as ex2.example.com how could I configure this?

From what I understand, this would be easy to do using an A record on my DNS if the two servers had separate outward facing IP addresses. One A record for each server pointing to its unique outward IP. However, how do I get it to work when both servers are on the same outward address and different internal IP's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming these servers are sat behind a NAT router in order to share an external IP. I'm also assuming that you need them both to listen on the same port numbers (e.g. 80 & 443 for web servers)

If you can't get separate external IP addresses and if the two domains have to be served by separate physical servers, then your only option to my knowledge would be to put a reverse proxy in place.

Both A records would point to the external IP of the NAT router, which in turn would pass requests to the internal IP of the reverse proxy.

The reverse proxy would then distribute requests to the internal IP address of the right server dependent on the domain requested in the HTTP request headers.

One example of server software that can perform the reverse proxy role is nginx, however there are many others. There are also hardware solutions if you have large sites and lots of money to spend.

If your scenario would allow each server to listen on different ports then you could skip the reverse proxy step and just setup separate port forwards for each server on the NAT router. I'm assuming these are public facing web servers however, in which case you will not want to do this.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Looks like a reverse proxy is exactly what I needed. Cheers!